# How do I get the the open items to stay open when using slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the js for the large handle

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery( ".docit-main-header" ).click(function() { 
     jQuery(this).nextUntil().find('.docit-sub-post').slideToggle();
     jQuery(this).nextUntil().find('.docit-sub-sub-menu-wrap').slideToggle();
});
```

This is the js for the small handle

```
jQuery( ".docit-sub-header" ).click(function() {
   jQuery(this).nextUntil('div').slideToggle();
 });
```

How can this be fixed so if you click on the small handle, which will close an item, then click on the big handle that the open one stays open and the others slide open. Instead of flip flopping. Here is an example on [jsfiddle.net/6U6fC/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/6U6fC/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the easiest way is to add classes to the .docit-main-cat-title items (like open, or active). When you click on the header, is all of them have the opened class, you close them all. If not, you open them all.

The other option is to check if all of them are visible or not with something like .filter(":visible"), and to act accordingly.

Comment: Right you are, any chance you could fix my jsfiddle to work like that. I have tried quite a few different ways with no luck.

Comment: Take a look at this, overall it works: http://jsfiddle.net/6U6fC/11/. Anyway, I think that the HTML is complicated and redundant. Try to simplify it.

Comment: Just checked out the jsfiddle and it does not seem to be working. Am I missing something? Thanks for you help!

Comment: This one is better, although the problem was just that clicking on the brackets didn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/6U6fC/12/

Comment: Nice job, that works perfect! How can you extend now so if we have multiple menus it only opens on main section instead of all of them. http://jsfiddle.net/6U6fC/13/ This is a plugin that was just released, and you can believe we'll add credit to you for your help. http://wordpress.org/plugins/slick-doc-it/

Comment: Try to establish a context, which is the parent container for the menu. http://jsfiddle.net/6U6fC/14/

I'm not sure if all of this is consistent enough to be released as a public plugin, though!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling slideToggle on 'sub-post' and 'sub-menu-wrap' each time.
jQuery 'toggle' functions will open anything that is closed and close anything that is open.

Try creating a condition and using `:visible` in your selectors so slideToggle is only called on visible or hidden elements.